# What is wrong with this delete function? It does not seem to be responding to the axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, crud

```
    deleteCreation: function (name) {
        return axios.delete("/api/deleteCreation", heroname).then(console.log("Deleted from DB", name)) 
      } 

   app.delete("/deleteCreation", function (name, res) {
      db.created.remove({
        name: mongojs.name
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
          res.json(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

I send a string called 'heroname' through axios to my server in hopes of deleting the object that has the heroname. I am sure I am messing something up in the app.delete function on the server page but cannot figure it out.

Comment: in the callback to `app.delete`, just because you call the first argument `name` doesn't change what that argument is - it's the request obejct - not your `heroname` string

Comment: I updated the code, but it still doesn't to be doing anything at all on the app.delete

Comment: lol ... I was referring to `function (name, res) {` - so you broke `deleteCreation: function (name) {`